# recursively append variable to result of curl

Tags: bash, curl

I using curl and putting the output into a file. The following script prepends a string `mystring` to the output:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1

ids=$(head ${file} | awk '{print $1}')

for i in ${ids}
do
    curl -sS http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/$i.fasta -w "mystring" >> test1.txt
done
```

which is fine and I get:

```
$ ./myscript.sh
mystring>Q12345
mystring>P79403
mystring>Q27595
```

However when trying to prepend a variable by doing:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1

ids=$(head ${file} | awk '{print $1}')

for i in ${ids}
do
    curl -sS http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/$i.fasta -w "$ids" >> test1.txt
done
```

I get:

```
$ ./myscript.sh
myvar1>Q12345
myvar1
myvar1
myvar1
myvar2>P79403
myvar2
myvar2
myvar2
myvar3>Q27595
myvar3
myvar3
myvar3
```

So it *kind of* works - but it's adding extra lines. How should I edit my script?

Comment: Did you mean `$i` in the `curl` command and not `$ids`?

Comment: BTW, that's not the best-practices way to iterate over a list of lines from a file or stream. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl -sS http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/$i.fasta -w "$ids" >> test1.txt
```

should presumably be

```
curl -sS "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/$i.fasta" -w "$i" >> test1.txt
```